# Tomar el ultimo dia que pasó del mes seleccionado

Tags: php

Buen día,

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna función en PHP para tomar el último día que pasó del mes seleccionado.

Por ejemplo, si seleccio el mes de Septiembre, por ser un mes que ya pasó debería retornar el día "30" pero si selecciono el mes de Octubre debería retornar "1" que es el último día que pasó de ese mes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses "cal_days_in_month"

```
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 10, 2019);
```

Solo necesitas poner como parámetros, el calendario que usaras, el mes, y el año.

Para obtener el ultimo día del mes actual.

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Mas información](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

Comment: Con eso sólo obtenés el último día de cualquier fecha pero faltaría una lógica para obtener si está en el mes y año corriente.

Comment: Ok, ya edite la respuesta para que veas del mes actual.
Te recomiendo ampliamente que busques la respuesta a tu pregunta antes de consultar, no por no quererte ayudar, el proceso de búsqueda muchas veces nos amplia el panorama con muchas otras cosas que podemos utilizar en algunas otras ocasiones.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$last_day = 0;
$today = new DateTime();
// creo la fecha según el mes del 1 al 12
$month = DateTime::createFromFormat('n', 7);

// comparo si es el mismo mes
if ($today->format('m') == $month->format('m')) {
  // devuelve el día de la fecha actual
  $last_day = $today->format('j');
} else {
  // 't' devuelve el último día del mes 
  $last_day = $month->format('t');
}
echo $last_day;
```